# Delete a certain line and lines before and after the matched line

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

In a large .ahk file, i need to locate the text 'no label' in a line, delete 2 lines before that, delete 23 lines after that, and delete the line with 'no label' itself (26 lines total). There can be multiple cases of this in the file, and in all cases it needs to remove these 26 lines.

I have no knowledge of SED, AWK and so on, and I need this to run on a windows machine. Is it doable with a .bat or some other windows application that I'll be able to run?

Comment: It's enough to use google for this task. Even the links at the right side should solve your problem

Comment: Tried for a few hours on google, can easily find something to remove the 23 following lines, but not something that will remove the 2 lines before the matched text.

Comment: As a huge fan of Batch files and their versatility, I would probably use something else to do this... VBscript maybe?  Also, you're more likely to get help if you give it a go first and post what you tried (even if it's futile) :)

Comment: To give you some direction, using vbscript, I would read through the file line-by-line and then write each line to a new file unless it matched your criteria.  Once complete, rename the files.

Comment: I would have thought AutoHotKey could do this.

Comment: Squashman, as in when creating the .ahk file, or for removing the lines? The file is build by a large .php script, and I can't edit the .php to not create these 26 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "$="
SET "tempfile=%temp%\some-tempfile-name.txt"
ECHO.>"%tempfile%"
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q34397055.txt') DO (
 ECHO %%b|FIND "no label" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 CALL :saveline# %%a
)
IF NOT DEFINED $ COPY /b q34397055.txt u:\newfile.txt 2>NUL >nul&GOTO done
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r ".*" q34397055.txt^|findstr /v /b /g:"%tempfile%"') DO (
 ECHO(%%b
)
)>u:\newfile.txt
:done
DEL "%tempfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:saveline#
:: calculate START line number to delete
SET /a $=%1 - 2
:: number of lines to delete
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
FOR /l %%d IN (1,1,26) DO (
 >>"%tempfile%" ECHO(!$!:
 SET /a $+=1
)
GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q34397055.txt` containing some test data for my testing.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

Essentially, read the entire file, numbering each line in the format `line#:line content`

Use the `tokens` facility to extract the line number part, and if the line-content part contains the target string (it's not clear whether OP wants a line *containing* "no label" or whether a line *exactly matching* "no label" is required) then call `:saveline#` passing the line number.

In `:saveline#`, calculate the starting line of the block-to-be-deleted and then write the line numbers to be deleted to a file in the format (eg) `6:`..`32:`.

Then perform the same numbering trick, but this time filter the output for lines that do *not* contain (`/v`) at the beginning of the line (`/b`) any string in the tempfile of line-numbers-to-be-deleted.

Output any line-content parts that pass through the filter.

[Edit : to fix empty-output-if-no-target-found problem

Insert `set "$="` to ensure variable `$`is deleted at the start.

Insert `if not defined $...` line to detect whether `$` has been established (ie. `:saveline#` has been called at least once). Simply mechanically copy the source file to the destination if `:saveline#` has not been called, and then skip to the label `done` to delete the tempfile.

Insert the label `done`

Suggestion : establish variables to contain the source and destination filenames so that only one change need be made to change the filenames, not two or three.
]

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for the effort. I want it to trigger on a line containing 'no label'. This one worked like a charm, after some edit.
Only problem is, if a file does not contain the trigger line, then it outputs a empty file. Any way to go around that?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I will try this out tomorrow, or maybe after newyear.
I did change your original script, to output the file with date and time in the name, so no files will have the same name. It doesn't matter that the filename changes from the original.
This script will be used by a older woman who has absolutely no PC knowledge, so you just saved me (and her) a bunch of work.
Very nice work sir, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, challenge accepted.  This should do what you want in 100% [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) form.  I threw in a few comments but if you have questions feel free to ask.

First it scans the file for any instance of the `searchPhrase` (currently "no label").  If found it saves that line number as `refLine`*.  It then sets the upper bounds as `refLine` + 23 and the lower bounds as `refLine` - 2, as per your criteria.  If the current line number falls outside those bounds it will write the line to a new, temporary, file.  Once complete, it backs up the original file then deletes it and renames the temp file.

```powershell
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "sourceFile=c:\temp\batchtest\myfile.txt"
set "tempFile=c:\temp\batchtest\tempfile.txt"
set "searchPhrase=no label"
set /a lineNum=0

REM check file for search phrase, store line as refLine
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%sourceFile%) DO (
    set /a lineNum+=1
    echo !lineNum! = "%%i"
    if "%%i" == "%searchPhrase%" (
        echo Found "%searchPhrase%" on line !lineNum!
        set /a refLine=!lineNum!
    )
)

REM make backup
copy "%sourceFile%" "%sourceFile%-%DATE:/=-% %TIME::=-%.bak"

echo. 2>%tempFile%

REM Rewrite file 
set /a lineNum=0
    set /a lowEnd=%refLine%-2
    echo "Set low end to %lowEnd%"
    set /a highEnd=%refLine%+23
    echo "Set high end to %highEnd%"
FOR /F "delims=" %%i IN (%sourceFile%) DO (
    set /a lineNum+=1
    if !lineNum! GTR %lowEnd% (
        if !lineNum! LSS %highEnd% (
           echo "Skipping line #!lineNum!"
        )
    )
    if !lineNum! LSS %lowEnd% (
        echo "Writing Line !lineNum! %%i to temp file..."
        echo %%i >> %tempFile%
    )

    if !lineNum! GTR %highEnd% (
        echo "Writing Line !lineNum! %%i to temp file..."
        echo %%i >> %tempFile%
    )
)

REM get target filename only 
for %%F in ("%sourceFile%") do set fname=%%~nxF
REM del original file and rename tempfile
echo "Deleting original file..."
echo Y | del "%sourceFile%"
echo "Renaming %tempFile% to %fname%"
ren "%tempFile%" "%fname%"
```

*Note that it will currently only find one instance of "no label".  If you think there are multiple instances, just run the bat file again.  <strike>If a person wanted to, they could find multiple instances and store the line numbers to a 3rd, temporary, text file then use that to determine more complicated bounds for filtering.</strike>  Alternatively, you could put a loop around the entire thing and exit the loop when it doesn't find an instance of the `searchPhrase`.

Comment: Hi Scott, thank you for the effort.
Tried to run your code, but it just messsed up the file, removing blank lines and deleting the first 20-30 or so lines of the file.
Since I'm having trouble with understanding your code, I'm not able to figure out why.
With that said, Magoo's code below me seemed to do the trick. So thanks anyway. If I'm ever posting here again, I will bring more example information, as it is not easy for someone to try and code this 'blindfolded'.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get number of lines of sections to preserve in "copy.tmp" file
set last=0
(for /F "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N /C:"no label" input.ahk') do (
   set /A copy=%%a-3-last, last=copy+26
   echo !copy!
)) > copy.tmp


rem Read from input file
< input.ahk (

   rem Process all "copy-lines, skip-26" sections
   for /F %%n in (copy.tmp) do (
      for /L %%i in (1,1,%%n) do (
         set "line="
         set /P "line="
         echo(!line!
      )
      for /L %%i in (1,1,26) do set /P "line="
   )

   rem Copy the rest of lines after last section
   findstr "^"

) > output.ahk

del copy.tmp
move /Y output.ahk input.ahk
```

Comment: I tried running this, but could not get it to work. I kind of understand what's going on in the code, but no matter what I did, it always outputted the same as the original file + a lot of empty lines in the bottom.
Thank you a lot for the effort though, all of you guys are awesome!